# "two fried rice" or "two fried rices"

Tags: grammatical-number

Should I use:
 I would like to have two fried rice.

Or

I would like to have two fried rices.

Comment: 2 plates (portions) of fried rice.

Comment: "I would like to have two **Fried Rice**." Singular. Capitalize the item name. However, "Two Cokes for us, please." Let me know if you'd like to know why. Good Luck.

Comment: @Rathony This sounds like the best choice to me. Two (somethings) of Fried Rice -- 2 orders, 2 bowls, 2 plates, etc.

Answer (score 8):

I would choose neither of your original suggestions.  "Rice" is what we call a **mass noun**.  Mass nouns are usually things that are of amorphous shape or uncertain amount, like rice, sand, wool, or flour.  They don't take numbers or indefinite articles like "a" or "one" or "two" and they don't normally get pluralized; to count them, you need to use them with a unit of measurement, like
*a bucket of sand*
or
*two pounds of wool*

BUT...

In this case, "fried rice", as the name of a dish you might order at a restaurant, functions more like a compound noun or a title.  So it is not entirely wrong to count it!  If I (as a native AmE speaker) heard someone say, "*Two fried rice, please*", I probably wouldn't particularly notice.  ("Rices" still sounds wrong, because it's pluralizing a mass noun.)

But to be perfectly on the safe side, the best answer is probably to still treat it as a mass noun, and say,
**"I would like two orders of fried rice."**

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't it be better to say "Fried rice for two".
In the above two,  I would prefer "two fried rice"(considering its a name of dish & not the quantity to be referred.)

Comment: But that's not the question. :)

Comment: @Kris.. Updated, I should have adressed that ! Thanks :-)